# on 1st click opens camera and 2nd click captured image displays. when i reopen the app then it should display captured image on 1st click

Tags: android, image, gallery

i am trying to make a fragment that is having a layout with multiple buttons, on each button, we can capture different images and save them into gallery. i want to capture image on 1st click and on 2nd click on the same button i want to display the same image that has been saved with custom name into gallery. 
**when i reopen the gallery it asks again to capture the image, but i want to only display the image when it has already been clicked last time

`enter code here`**    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                   // if(uri.equals(uri))
                    clickcount1 = clickcount1 + 1;
                    if (clickcount1 == 1)
                    {

```
                    Intent in = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");
                   // SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH-mm-ss");

                    String datetime = sdf.format(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    Log.i("DateTime", datetime);
                    //String datetime = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date()).toString();
                    File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath(), "MY_Docs");
                    if (!folder.exists())
                        folder.mkdirs();
                    File file = new File(folder, "Aadhar_" + datetime + ".jpg");
                    try {
                        file.createNewFile();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.e("creating file exception", e.toString());
                    }
                    uriaadhar = Uri.fromFile(file);
                    Log.i("URI after file creation", uriaadhar.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "After file conversion to uri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    in.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uriaadhar);
                    startActivity(in);
                }

            if  (clickcount1 >= 2 )
            {
                    String filepath = uriaadhar.getPath();
                    Log.e("FilePath2", filepath);
                    AlertDialog.Builder ab = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.doc1, null);
                    ab.setView(v);
                    ab.setTitle("Aadhar Card");
                    ImageView ivAadhar = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.iv_Aadhar);
                    Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath);
                //Code for marshmallow to display image in imageview
                int nh = (int) ( bitmap.getHeight() * (512.0 / bitmap.getWidth()) );
                Bitmap scaled = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 600, nh, true);

                    ivAadhar.setImageBitmap(scaled);
                    //ivAadhar.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath));
                    ab.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                            dialogInterface.dismiss();
                        }
                    });
                    ab.show();

            }

        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Make your click count variable static

```
private static int clickcount1 = 0;
```

Or you can save the state of your mode in to sharedPeference so you can reuse it whenever your want.

Comment: can you please xplain the use of code line clickcount1=2; 
i am unable to understand it..

Comment: I get misunderstading with your question just use static as your variable or use sort of data storage to store the value so when your application launch again it know which button already taken photo in last step. I will be edit the answer.